# 2 quartz jobs scheduled, but only one executed twice

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I have a custom `Job` with a custom `JobFactory` so each job can have different parameters (here: logging to a different file). But when I schedule different jobs with the same class, only the later scheduled is executed but twice. I even tried to duplicate all the code, extending my custom job twice so the `MyJob.class` can be different in the `JobBuilder` but it was still the same problem. Even if every factory gets it's own class and a lot of code duplication it still just executes the one job.

```
public class TripJob implements Job {

    private TripParser parser;
    private CsvWriter writer;

    public TripJob() {

    }

    public void setParser(TripParser parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public void setWriter(CsvWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        if (parser == null || writer == null) throw new JobExecutionException(getClass().getName() + "'s parser and/or writer not set");
        String result = parser.getResult();
        writer.write(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")) + result);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class TripJobFactory extends SimpleJobFactory {

    private final TripParser parser;
    private final CsvWriter writer;

    public TripJobFactory(TripParser parser, CsvWriter writer) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler Scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        TripJob job = (TripJob) super.newJob(bundle, Scheduler);
        if (parser == null || writer == null) throw new SchedulerException(getClass().getName() + "'s parser and/or writer not set");
        job.setParser(parser);
        job.setWriter(writer);
        return job;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class TripScheduler {

    private final TripJobFactory factory;

    public TripScheduler(TripJobFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void scheduleJob(String schedule) throws SchedulerException {
        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.start();

        var jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(TripJob.class)
                .build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .startNow()
                //.withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?"))
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(schedule))
                .build();

        scheduler.setJobFactory(factory);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
}
```

In my main class I call

```
    var toParser = new TripParser(toUrl);
    var toWriter = new CsvWriter("logs/to.csv");
    var toFactory = new TripJobFactory(toParser, toWriter);
    var toScheduler = new TripScheduler(toFactory);

    var fromParser = new TripParser(fromUrl);
    var fromWriter = new CsvWriter("logs/from.csv");
    var fromFactory = new TripJobFactory(fromParser, fromWriter);
    var fromScheduler = new TripScheduler(fromFactory);

    try {
        toScheduler.scheduleJob("0 * * * * ?");
        fromScheduler.scheduleJob("30 * * * * ?");
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is

```
Wrote '19:53:34;24.0;Min.;24.3;km' to: logs/from.csv
Wrote '19:54:04;24.0;Min.;24.3;km' to: logs/from.csv
```

But should be

```
Wrote '19:53:34;24.0;Min.;24.3;km' to: logs/from.csv
Wrote '19:54:04;25.0;Min.;25.3;km' to: logs/to.csv
```

Comment: try adding `.withIdentity("myJob")` to your job creation, basically you will pass the jobName to your scheduleJob method . May be two jobs are not getting created..

Comment: I already did try identities and/or groups. Did not solve the problem.